# How do I load a HTML table sections at a time

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, twitter, html-table

I have a table that will rebuild async every time a new option is selected from a dropdown. I am able to make the call and the HTML is generated correctly but when sending it back across the wire it breaks if the size is to large.

I was thinking a solution would be query sections of the table until all rows are returned by making separate calls each time. Then I thought of how Twitter does their feeds and add more if the user scrolls to the bottom of the list.

Any suggestions?

Here is some Code examples of what I'm trying to do:

```
$('[id$=ddCorpIngredientClasses]').change(function () {

        callScriptMethod(
        'IngredientProperties.aspx/ReBuildCorpIngredientTable',

        { 'ingredientClass': $(this).val() },
        function (result) {
            $('[id$=_SlideOutPanelBodyTable]').empty();
            $(result).each(function () {

                var row = this.toString();

                $('[id$=_SlideOutPanelBodyTable]').append(row);

            });
            adjustBodytable();
        });

    });


function callScriptMethod(url, jsonObject, callback, async) {

    callback = callback || function () { };
    async = (async == null || async);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',

    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    url: url,
    data: JSON.stringify(jsonObject),
    dataType: 'json',
    async: async,
    success: function (jsonResult) {
        if ('d' in jsonResult)
            callback(jsonResult.d);
        else
            callback(jsonResult);
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("Error calling '" + url + "' " + JSON.stringify(jsonObject));
        callback([]);
    }
});
}
```

Comment: "it breaks if the size is to large" What do you mean by this? How large? What do you mean by "breaks"?  Also, are you using GET or POST?

Comment: Do you have any code samples? What exactly are you sending, from where, with what protocol and where to?

Comment: lonesomeday, I am POSTing and the query I am wanting to bring back has about 400 rows in it. By break I mean it wont come back to the client from the server. When I debug, it has the all the correct values but on the return my JSON call dies.

Comment: I fixed this problem by taking out the .each statement and just appending the entire array. This increase the performance on my screens a ton. So if you are seeing lag problems look for a for loop in your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [SlickGrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki) with a AJAX data source. ([Demos here.](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/Examples))

Basically, you only load 50 rows at a time.  As the user scrolls, the next 50 rows are requested and seamlessly rendered.  Additionally, SlickGrid dynamically creates and removes DOM elements as the user scrolls, so there's never physically more rows than what is on the screen.  This means SlickGrid can handle literally *millions* of rows without flinching.

Comment: This is cool. I think I am going to try and use some of their ideas.

Answer (score 4):

I believe you are looking for this:

- http://www.infinite-scroll.com/
- [Load content while scrolling with jquery](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/load-content-while-scrolling-with-jquery/)

There are lots of plugins out there but I think the second link is your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a form of pagination on your backend in order to limit the number of rows it returns. Then, fire an event in JQuery to pull new rows into the table using AJAX by incrementing the page number request.

We need more information before giving actual solutions.